# Illegal string offset in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, get

I'm using Laravel, and it complains about $header inside the Form::text being a illegal string offset, how do I fix this? It doesn't complain if I go straight into the page, but if I submit a form with get method going into the page. I searched around and maybe it thinks $header is an array?

```
<?php 
        $header = null;
        if(isset($_GET["header"])) {
            $header = $_GET["header"];
        }

        echo Form::text('header', $header, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Tittel'));
?>
```

Comment: 1) Please use `{}` because it makes code 829X more readable. 2) You are missing a semicolon after `echo From::text(); // <-- THIS ONE`

Comment: Sorry, cleaned up the syntax a little bit now.

Comment: Is it still giving you the same error?

Comment: Yes, but the answer below fixed it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel clears the $_GET array. You need to use `Input::has('header')` and `Input::get('header')` instead.

Comment: You're right, I phrased that badly. Thanks for your correction.